# Photoshop: How to dock the floating Contextual Task Bar?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design, selections, tools, background-removal

This is possibly Adobe's most annoying idea yet.

<sup>(Photoshop version 24.5.0)</sup>

I don't know what to call it, but just look at this thing constantly encroaching on my space:

[image]

Essentially, these two large buttons that perform functions specific only to the recently introduced generative AI features... will follow you around no matter what part of your document you're working on.

Because you know... all graphic designers do all day is isolate subjects from backgrounds. And we've never heard of keyboard shortcuts, so all of us need this omnipresent toddler bar to remind us that we should be using the hot new AI features, on every image.

<sup>(The new AI features are honestly great. Nothing kills my enthusiasm for them more than this panel.)</sup>

So please, what is this UI element called? And more importantly, how to I dock it or kill it?

---

**Update:** I've found out it's called the **Contextual Task Bar**, and that the ellipsis button `...` can hide it. But now, having hidden it, I don't know where to find the buttons when I actually need them:

- Select Subject
- Remove Background

etc.

I also can't seem to reveal the bar again, because **View → Show** does not presently include "Contextual Task Bar" in the list of items that can be shown.

But even if I could bring it back and have it in my way again, I would rather be able to call upon the functionality of its buttons from some other (non-floating) area of the UI, or via keyboard shortcuts.

<sub>Please help me restore my sanity. :-)</sub>

Comment: You can't. It's not possible to dock the bar.  You can pin it though. If you hide it, you can get it back under *Window > Contextual Task Bar*

Comment: Adobes problem is that they need to sell you new features all the time. At least this isn't as useless as some of the other ideas

Comment: @joojaa - Hopefully in time Adobe will improve it to fit the interface a bit better. It is kind of annoying at the moment.

Comment: To the OP: Select Subject is also available under the Select main menu, and Select Subjcect and Remove Background are available as buttons in the Properties panel under Quick Actions. You may have to scroll down the panel to find it.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you for everything you mentioned! I forgot to add: Despite having pinned it, it has been coming unpinned, and I don't know what causes that. Knowing that **Select Subject** and **Remove Background** are available in the **Properties** panel is very helpful! Thanks for sharing how to get the Contextual Task Bar back as well! Care to post as an answer? (Will accept.)

Comment: to be honest i doubt it. These kinds of things seem to be management motivated. Their purpose is prrhaps to prove some internal point. Usually thus they are also abandoned into the gui after the poit has been or has not been demonstrated

Comment: @joojaa I imagine it going down something like this at Adobe... **Dev A:** What should we implement next? **Dev B:** Make rendered Filters and Layer Style effects resolution-independent to keep with the times? **Dev A:** Nah, not sexy enough. **Dev B:** How about freeing up all possible combinations of modifier keys for use in shortcuts? **Dev A:** Too practical, not buzz-worthy. **Dev B:** What if we made a cute little floaty bar that sticks itself under whatever the user is working on? **Dev A:** Revolutionary! Who could possibly hate *that*? Get coding! Have Marketing draft a blog post! :-)

Comment: @Mentalist i doubt the devs make that call replace Dev A with product manager X and dev b by marketting manager Y

Comment: @joojaa Agreed. I know "developer" probably isn't even in the job titles of the people calling the shots, but for brevity's sake... Because I couldn't fit "Senior Director of UI/UX something-something" in my comment. And who knows exactly what their titles are anyway? ;-)

Comment: OK. I've added my comments as an answer now.  As for the contextual task bar unpinning itself that may be something you might want to report to Adobe - a potential bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It's not possible to dock the bar. You can pin it though. If you hide it, you can get it back under *Window > Contextual Task Bar*

*Select Subject* is also available under the *Select* main menu, and *Select Subject* and *Remove Background* are available as buttons in the Properties panel under Quick Actions. You may have to scroll down the panel to find it.